# How to select the nth position from a string vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, position

How does one find, let's say, the 2nd position from a string vector?

Here's a string vector example:

```
1 2 3 4 Hi
7 8 9 0 Bye
2 2 5 6 World
```

If I use `example.at(2)`, it gives me the whole row `2 2 5 6 World`.

I just want to get `2` from the 1st row instead of getting the whole line of `2 2 5 6 World`. How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you should make a `Record` class that stores the individual columns as distinct variables and then you can have a `std::vector<Record> records;`.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `example.at(2)` is the 3rd item in your vector, in this case, a  `std::string`.

To access a specific character in your string, you can use the `operator[]`. So to select 2 from the first row, you would simply need to do the following:

```
example.at(0)[2];
```

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! If you wouldn't mind please upvote my comment and click the checkmark! I need to increase my points lol

Answer (score 1):

So what you actually have is `vector` of `string` where `string` represents another dimension, so you have an table with both rows and columns, similar to an 2D array, in other to access a single cell you need 2 indexes, one index for position in `vector` and another for position in `string`.

So in your case it would be `example[0][0]` to get first `char` of a string in first row, and to get one you are looking for you would need to write `example.at(0)[2]`;

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> strings;
  strings.push_back("1234Hi");
  strings.push_back("7890Bye");
  std::cout << strings.at(0)[1] << std::endl; // prints 2
  std::cout << strings.at(1)[1] << std::endl; // prints 8
}
```

It's sort of like a two-dimensional array: each string you push to the vector is analogous to the  first dimension, and then each character of the string is analogous to the second dimension.

But as mentioned above, there may be better ways to do this, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers show you how to access individual numbers in your strings, but they assume that the numbers are always 1 digit in length.  If you ever need to support multi-digit numbers, use [`std::istringstream()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) or [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead to parse the strings.